# How get last inserted ID in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

How to get the last inserted ID in SQL Server 2012? It shows null for me.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming table is

```
create table test
(
    id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
    , testData varchar(100) NOT NULL
)
```

this works

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (testData) VALUES ('test')
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS ID
```

as does this (better answer)

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Test (testData) VALUES ('test')
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS ID
```

I don't have enough information to know why yours does not work. It is probably in the table structure? I would need more information to answer this.

Comment: You can use IDENTITY(1,1) instead of the function. Both @@IDENTITY and SCOPE_IDENTITY work off this construct. If you are using a separate function (in a TRIGGER perhaps?) then it is not an IDENTITY, it is a custom auto number function. If you want to use your function, then grab the ID first and insert into the table as part of your insert table. Otherwise, switch back to IDENTITY in the table definition.

Comment: You should use scope_identity over @@IDENTITY. If you ever put a trigger on your table that inserts to an audit table or something like that you will get that identity when using @@IDENTITY. Also there is IDENT_CURRENT. Here is a decent article that explains all three of them. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/

Answer (score 3):

One way would be

```
insert into your_table (...)
output INSERTED.ID 
values (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `@@ROWCOUNT` with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` to get latest inserted ID in table as following:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.MyTable (...) VALUES (...)

SELECT ID
FROM [dbo].MyTable
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```